# Querying an array of strings with a string that represents search terms

Tags: postgresql, array, string-splitting, string-searching

I have an array of values like:

```
array ('hello world', 'foo', 'bar') -- terms here have only letters and one space at most
```

and some text like: `'foo hello-world hello1world'`

and I would like to get back from the original array the values `foo` and `hello world` filtering out `bar`.

Is there any way to get that with Postgres?

Comment: That's still really weird. how come you want `hello1world` to match `hello world`

Comment: If you are interested in more fuzzy matching, Pavel Stěhule has a LIKE version using arrays at http://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks#LIKE_to_list_of_patterns

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this,

1. create a helper function to generate your query terms from the text-string input. You could inline this into the function, but it's ugly and silly and if you need it here then you probably need it elsewhere.
2. Write a query with `NOT word LIKE ANY()`

Here is a demo of the helper function,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_stupid_query(q text)
RETURNS text[] AS $$

  SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT regexp_replace(t, '[^[:alpha:]]', '_', 'g')
    FROM unnest(string_to_array(q, ' ')) AS q(t)
  );

$$ LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

Then you can use `NOT word LIKE ANY()`. This shows what it would look like,

```
SELECT word
FROM (VALUES (ARRAY['hello world', 'foo', 'bar'])) AS t1(x)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(x) AS t2(word)
WHERE NOT word LIKE ANY(my_stupid_query('foo hello-world helloXworld'));

 word 
------
 bar
(1 row)
```